# Why do I keep on getting this error "error: unexpected type"

Tags: java, oop, compiler-errors

I get the same error when compiling this code. I wanted to know how I can successfully add the Rental Days and Rental Rate. Please Help.

```
 Tractor.java:83: error: unexpected type
         RentalDays + RentalRate = RentalProfit;
                    ^
 required: variable
  found value
1 error
```

code:

```
 import java.util.*;

 public class Tractor
{
   private String name;
   private int VehicleID; 
   private int RentalRate;
   private int RentalDays;


   public int setRentalRate(int RentalRate)
{
    if (RentalRate <= 0 || RentalRate > 100000) 
    {
      return -1;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return this.RentalRate;

    }
 }

public int getRentalRate()
 {
     return this.RentalRate;
 }

  public int setRentalDays(int RentalDays)
{
    if (RentalDays <= 0 || RentalDays > 365) 
    {
      return -1;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return this.RentalDays;

    }
 }

public int getRentalDays()
 {
     return this.RentalRate;
 }

  public int RentalProfit(int RentalRate, int RentalDays)
  {
     int RentalProfit;

     RentalDays + RentalRate = RentalProfit;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
int RentalProfit;

     RentalDays + RentalRate = RentalProfit;
```

to

```
    return RentalDays + RentalRate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write code to add.

```
public int RentalProfit(int RentalRate, int RentalDays)
{
  return RentalDays + RentalRate;
}
```

`RentalDays + RentalRate = RentalProfit;` is invalid because lefthand size of `=` operator should be a variable to assign to, not result of addition.
Did you mean `RentalProfit = RentalDays + RentalRate;`?